# Finding integral points on a surface

Tags: equation-solving, computational-geometry

Suppose I have a dimension formula (for a Lie algebra representation) that is as follows:
$$
d(a,b) = {(a+1)(b+1)(a+b+2) \over 2}
$$
Now consider the surface $F(a,b,n) = 0 = d(a,b) -n$ where $n \in \Bbb N$. Is there a Mathematica function that would allow me to find triples $(a,b,n) \in \Bbb N^3$ on this surface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If what you really want is to find *all* natural numbers $a$ and $b$ on the surface for a *given* $n$, a search among the divisors of $2n$ will do it efficiently even for sizable values of $a$ and $b$.  To do this, we find all divisors $k$ of $2n$ (`Divisors`), then all divisors of the quotient $2n/k$ (`Divisors` again), forming triples $(u,v,w)$ for which $uvw=2n$ (`Flatten@Table`).  Then it remains only to screen for those of the form $u=a+b+2, v=b+1, w=a+1$ (`Cases`) and remove any duplicates (`Union`).

```
d[a_, b_] := (a + 1) (b + 1) (a + b + 2)/2;

AbsoluteTiming[
 With[{n = d[119, 599]}, 
  Union[Cases[
   Flatten[Table[
    Outer[{#1, #2, 2 n/(#1 #2)} &, First[k], Last[k]], 
     {k, {{#}, Divisors[2 n/#]} & /@ Divisors[2 n]}], 2], 
      {c_, b_, a_} /; c == a + b && b >= a :> {a - 1, b - 1}]]]]
```

> $$\{0.0600035,\{\{19,1599\},\{59,899\},\{119,599\},\{239,359\}\}\}$$

($0.06$ seconds to find all four solutions for $n=d(119, 599) = 25\ 920\ 000$.)

Although the method works for any positive $n$, this example begins with an $n$ formed from a particular $a$ and $b$ in order to check that we at least get $(a,b)$ back in the output.  (Try it on some factorials, such as $13!$ [no output] and $14!$ [one solution].)

---

#### Edit

To solve $n = (a+1)(b+1)(a+b+2)/2$ for a given $n$, write $x=a+b+2$, $y=b-a$ (which is non-negative with no loss of generality), whence we can recover $a = (x-y)/2-1$ and $b=(x+y)/2-1$, and note

$$y^2 = x^2 - 8n/x.$$

Therefore we can reduce a quadratic-time search to a linear-time search (in the number of divisors of $n$) by ranging over $x$, computing the right-hand side, and checking whether it is a square:

```
AbsoluteTiming[With[{n = 3240},
  Cases[Union[
    Cases[Divisors[8 n], x_ /; x^3 >= 8 n 
      && Sqrt[x^2 - 8 n/x] \[Element] Integers :> {x, Sqrt[x^2 - 8 n/x]}]], 
    {x_, y_} /; EvenQ[x - y] :> {(x - y)/2 - 1, (x + y)/2 - 1}]]]
```

> $$\{0.0020001,\{\{11,17\},\{5,29\},\{2,44\},\{0,79\}\}\}$$

Because it is possible to get some spurious answers where $x$ and $y$ have opposite parity (for then $a$ and $b$ are only half-integral), those are screened out when converting back to $a$ and $b$.

The speedup gets better with larger $n$; *e.g.*, the answers for $20!$ can be computed in $12$ seconds ($\{\{1270079,1422719\},\{484703,2935295\},\{355679,3525119\},\{235199,4432319\}\}$).

Comment: This is fantastic thanks very much whuber

Comment: You're welcome. You shouldn't be so quick to accept this answer, though: this community does a great job of improving answers over the course of a day or two. Much better answers might appear soon :-).

Comment: I appreciate the explanation in this answer. +1

Comment: The equation is a cubic (parameterized by $n$), so it's possible a more efficient method to obtain all solutions can be found by computing generators of its group of integral points.  But typically these groups are so small--I haven't found one larger than $12$ yet--as a practical matter it might not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
numPoints = 10;
dd[a_, b_, n_] := (a + 1) (b + 1) (a + b + 2)/2 - n
FindInstance[
 dd[aa, bb, nn] == 0 && aa > 0 && bb > 0 && nn > 0, {aa, bb, 
  nn}, Integers, numPoints]
```

One could be slicker, but this works.